# Pyinstaler why does my exe file not run while my script is?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

first of all I'm new to python, so sorry for evantually missing information.

Im currently trying to compile a running script into an exe file. As I mentioned the script is running perfectly in python (anaconda 3).
I used pyinstaller with the auto-py-tp-exe gui. It compiles my file into an exe, but when I try to run it it doesnt work.

I used the following options:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed  ""
```

Of course with the file path. I get the following error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MAIN_INTERFACE.py", line 2673, in <module>
  File "MAIN_INTERFACE.py", line 343, in __init__
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 2790, in create_image
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 2776, in _create
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage10" doesn't exist
```

Does anybody know what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

i can't actually tell exactly without the source code, but this heavly seems like a problem with the python garbage collector (might sound a little scarry, but it really isn't):

I could imagine, that your code looks something like this:

```
my_tkinstance = Tk()

my_image = PhotoImage("path_to_image")
my_label = Label(my_tkinstance, image=my_image)
my_label.pack()

my_tkinstance.mainloop()
```

If we think through, that the interpreter does with this code, we can come up with this:

1. Create the Tkinter instance.
2. Read in the image from the specified path
3. Create the label **With the image**
4. Pack the label on the screen
5. Show the tkinter instance.
   But here is the clue:
   After the last line of code (step 5) is completed pythons so called garbage collector goes through your variables and thinks like "hmm. This **image** variable doesn't seem to be used anymore, I will go ahead and delete it".

To prevent this from happening you have to modify the code like this:
my_tkinstance = Tk()

```
my_image = PhotoImage("path_to_image")
my_label = Label(my_tkinstance, image=my_image)
my_label.image = my_image
my_label.pack()

my_tkinstance.mainloop()
```

In this way you refrence the image in a different part of your python code (so to speak) and the garbage collector doesn't delete the image.

Hope this helps :)